# Asking for suggestions on RADIUS (AAA protocol)

Tags: c++, c, linux, radius

As an intern in a telecom corp, I am about to dive into some AAA system implementation on Linux C/C++. I did some simple search but failed to find a thorough tutorial that would involve a number of sample codes. All in all, I have to be bound to start off myself so could anyone give me some suggestions on RADIUS programming on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RADIUS is a protocol so defined in a RFC, AAA is an auth used by Radius for accounting and is also defined in a RFC. The Wikipedia page on [RADIUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RADIUS) provides you with links to this two RFCs ([Radius](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2865), and [Radius Accounting](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2866)).

You have two ways to do it:

- You are lucky enough to find libraries or framework in C/C++ (that are Linux compatible) and use them to program your system.
- You are unlucky and read the RFC to implement the protocols in your system.

Comment: yeah fortunately i have found freeradius work for me.im trying to program with freeradius linux c framework by the numbers.the bad news is i didnt find any handy instructions for using freeradius APIs...time to exceed my limits..

Comment: If there is no doc for the library, i suggest you to use a source document generator like Doxygen to extract info. You will then be able to see dependencies and read the code more easily.

Comment: The server libraries already have many doxygen comments, and the doxygen docs are rebuilt automatically after every commit to the master branch of the FreeRADIUS GitHub repo. See http://doc.freeradius.org for the output.

Note: The server libraries are not intended to be used by 3rd parties, they're more there to help manage code complexity within the server. The API is not guaranteed to be subversion stable and may change at any time.

Comment: The API may stabalise in 3.1/4.0, but in the mean time you may be better off using the ``radclient`` utility or the freeradius-client library https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-client.